# print value_counts for columns in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am using bokeh to print horizontal bar charts for a number of columns. I used for loop for the same. This is the code, but when I run this. I get this error. I am a beginner in bokeh. Please help.

```
chart_cols = ['respondent_age respondent_gender respondent_edu respondent_occupation Religion Caste_cat CM_choice Likely_winner'.split()]
chart_cols
for f in chart_cols:
    count = df[f].value_counts()

    p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title='Chart',toolbar_location=None)

    p.title.align = "right"
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Number of respondents'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Something'

    p.hbar(y=sorted(df[f].unique()), height=0.7, left=0,
          right=count, color=Category20,
           alpha=0.7)
    show(p)
    print('Done')

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

To write the above code, I used bokeh documentation and data available with me. I tried

using `.` operator but error is same. In that case it says that no `.` attribute
For example `df.f.value_counts()`

What mistake am I doing? Please help.

Comment: You can only use `.value_counts` on a `pandas.Series`, not a `DataFrame`. Your chart_cols is not created properly.

Comment: `pandas.value_count(df[f]) `? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: Hi, for that I used .split() function to do it automatically :)

Comment: I applied both the methods pandas.value_counts(df[f]). it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra pair of square brackets in your chart_cols. Replace the first line by

```
chart_cols = 'respondent_age respondent_gender respondent_edu respondent_occupation Religion Caste_cat CM_choice Likely_winner'.split()
```

Comment: Does it mean that I cannot initialize a list of string inside closed square brackets?

Comment: You can, but then it becomes a list, containing a single list, i.e. `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`. What you want instead is `['a', 'b', 'c']`.
Also, as stated in another another comment,
`df[f].value_counts()` then becomes `df[['a', 'b', 'c']].value_counts()`

This means that you're trying to access the `value_counts()` attribute for a `pandas.DataFrame`. It's only defined for a `pandas.Series` however, so you get the error. Makes sense?